# Bokeh plot time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bokeh

I'm trying to plot the following dataframe with Bokeh (data_frame in the code), in my example I only have two columns 0 and 1 (and Dates which is the x-axis). But in my real dataset I have more than 10, so I'm trying to find a better version than mine which does not generalize well. (I thought of a for loop but it doesn't seem optimal)

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.charts import TimeSeries
from bokeh.io import output_notebook

output_notebook()

data_frame = pd.DataFrame({0: [0.17, 0.189, 0.185, 0.1657], 1: [0.05, 0.0635, 0.0741, 0.0925], 'Date': [2004, 2005, 2006, 2007]})
p = figure(x_axis_label = 'date',
       y_axis_label='Topics Distribution')

p.circle(data_frame.Date, data_frame.iloc[:, 0])
p.circle(data_frame.Date, data_frame.iloc[:, 1])

show(p)
```

I've tried this as well, but it does not work and I don't want lines only points:

```
p = TimeSeries(data_frame, index='Date', legend=True,
          title = 'T', ylabel='topics distribution')
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try a different approach and see if this makes a little more sense:

- Reshape the data to be in a
  ["tidy"](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) data format
- Use Bokeh high-level Scatter chart with color argument

Code:

```
chartdata = data_frame.set_index('Date').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Category',0:'Value'})

print(chartdata)
```

Output "tidy" data format:

```
   Date  Category   Value
0  2004         0  0.1700
1  2004         1  0.0500
2  2005         0  0.1890
3  2005         1  0.0635
4  2006         0  0.1850
5  2006         1  0.0741
6  2007         0  0.1657
7  2007         1  0.0925
```

Build chart:

```
from bokeh.charts import Scatter
p = Scatter(chartdata, x='Date', y='Value', color='Category',xlabel='date', ylabel='Topics Distribution')
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I would have never thought about that, that''s exactly what I want. thanks a lot :)